# An algorithm for check if a dot(x,y) in inside an area?

Tags: geometry, constraints, computational-geometry, area

Let's say that every black line in this picture can be described as an equation `y = Ki*x + Mi` where `Ki` is the i:th slope and `Mi` is the i:th bias of the straight line equation. I also know the dots of every corner of the lines.

The blue is my data. My problem here is that I want to pick a dot with the coordinates `x,y` and place it inside the area that the lines create, then I'm going to get a `YES` or `NO` back.

But I don't know how to do that. My question is: Is there an algorithm for this problem, or do I have to use a lot of `if-statements` to solve this kind of `area` issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the sign of (y - Ki * x - Mi) is positive for all bottom edges and negative for all top edges.

[image]

For N sides, this is exactly N tests :-)

---

If you don't know which are the bottom and top edges, you can test if the signs are the same as for any point known to be inside.

Comment: Yes! I solved this yesterday. Point-in-polygon algorithm. Try the algorithm in CControl at GitHub

Comment: What I described is the point-in-convex-polygon algorithm. It is simpler.

Comment: I have tried this algorithm https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Documents/Examples/ArtificialIntelligence/point_in_polygon.txt and it works perfect with MATLAB's `inpolygon' algorith.

Comment: Try that if you want.

Comment: @MrYui: you are the asker. I absolutely know about PIP algorithms !

Comment: yes, but if you could confirm if I have made it right? The C code is this. I hope this will work for all polygons. https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl/blob/master/src/CControl/Sources/ArtificialIntelligence/point_in_polygon.c

Comment: @MrYui: it obviously fails with vertical sides.

Comment: What do you mean with vertical sides? I have made a very werid polygon and the algorithm gave the same results as the MATLAB function.

Comment: Can you show me a polygon that don't work with my algorithm?

Comment: @MrYui: yes I can, but I think I have done enough. Bye.